# Verify self-signed TLS certificate for HTTPS in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I use SSL certificate verification in GET Request in RUBY (using password parameter in URL)? ->

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(ARGV[0] || 'https://example.com?password=my_password')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

if uri.scheme == "https" 

    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
    http.ca_file=File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),
             "/Users/me/Desktop/demp.pem")
end

http.start do
    http.request_get(uri.path) do |res|

print res.body

end

end
```

--> output

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: I've tried multiple things, so just wanted a small script to verify ssl certificate in ruby.

Comment: It’s great that you tried some things. Please show your work. If we know what you’ve tried we can help you understand why it didn’t work and how to make it work, rather than writing the code for you.

Comment: added! I need to add parameters to the url and then validate it through ssl cert

Comment: I've edited your title to be more on-point, but if this isn't the intention of your question please clarify further.

Comment: I need to write a ruby script which uses an http get request to validate an ssl certificate. The request must contain -> url and parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'
require 'uri'
require 'json'


ContentURI = URI.parse("example.com")
@cert_raw = File.read('cert.pem')
TestDataPath = '.'

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(ContentURI.path)
https = Net::HTTP.new(ContentURI.host, ContentURI.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(@cert_raw)
https.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@cert_raw)
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
resp = https.start { |cx| cx.request(req) }
p resp
p resp.body
```